# hide QLabel based on text-size

Tags: qt, text, label, autoresize

I would like to write a custom QLabel subclass with some more features for responsive design. In thisexample, I want to write a QLabel which scales the text based on the useable space. This is quite easy but also has some problems because of Qt-intern stuff. (I have to scale the text to 0.9 of the useable space, otherwise resizing the window / widget gets buggy)

Now I wan't to add a way to hide the label completely when the font size is bellow a specific threshold. However, this seems to be quite a complex task.

Here is what I have sofar in the classes `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)` function.
Right now, my function only sets the text to `""` when the size would be bellow the threshold.

```cpp
void CustomLabel::resizeEvent (QResizeEvent * event ) {
    if(autoFontResize) {
        this->setSilentText(labelText); // just the normal setText function, I overwrote it for the subclass
        QFont f = this->font();
        int flags = Qt::TextDontClip|Qt::TextWordWrap;
        QRect fontBoundRect = this->fontMetrics().boundingRect(this->rect(), flags, this->text());
        float xFactor = (float)event->size().width()  / (float)fontBoundRect.width();
        float yFactor = (float)event->size().height() / (float)fontBoundRect.height();
        float factor = xFactor < yFactor ? xFactor : yFactor;

        f.setPointSizeF(f.pointSize()*factor*0.9); // 
        if(minimumFontSize != 0) { // 0 = no minimum Size for the font
            if(f.pointSize() < minimumFontSize) {
                if(hideFontOnMinimum) {  // either Hide or set to the limit size
                    this->setSilentText(""); //replace text                 
                } else {
                    f.setPointSizeF(minimumFontSize);
                }
            } 
        }

        this->setFont(f);
    }
    QLabel::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

By the way, some parts of the code are found on stackoverflow, not mine. ;)
What I would like to do is to completely `hide()` the label. However the label doesn't know when It can `show()` again since the resizeEvent doesn't seem to be called after that.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, if you call hide() on the widget it fails to receive a resize event. Since you're customising the class anyway, rather than calling hide(), you could just set a class variable to note that it's hidden and overload the paintEvent function, not to draw the widget if the variable is set: -

```
void CustomLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    if(m_hideOnMinimum)
        return;

    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
}
```

Note that by not painting the label, it will be hidden, but the user may still be able to interact with it, so you will need to disable it or overload keyboard / mouse events too.

Comment: This would hide the label but it would still reserve Space. :(
I also tried to set the width to a fixed value of 0. Didn't worked either.

Comment: You mean space within a layout? Yes it would, though you could remove it from the layout too.

Comment: If I would remove it from the layout, how would the label detect if there is enough space to display again? ;) You see my problem ;D

Comment: I do now; the question does not define what you mean by 'useable space'.

Comment: Mhh. 

That's the problem. ;) 
Lets say I have a label which scales the text to the biggest possible size and also scales the width to fit the text.
So when the height is the limiting factor, the unnecessary width will be cut off.

Now lets say the size of the font at some point drops down bellow a threshold. Know the label will be hidden until there is enough room for the label to scale the font  above the threshold.


The problem is how the label should know, when to view again. When it hides, other widgets will normaly take the place and not give it away again.

Comment: What I just noticed is that I might have to write a container widget which determins wheter or not the label is shown whenever it gets resized. ;)